# How to change UI language of django-ckEditor?

Tags: django, django-ckeditor

I am using ckEditor as my web-based post editor. I know that ckeditor is a multi-lingual application. The problem is that I don't know how could I change the UI from English version, to Arabic one, in Django-ckeditor?

Comment: did you find the solution for this?